# Веб сервер Java

Tags: java, сервер, сокет, heroku

Имеется Java сервер на Heroku. Получает запрос и должен вернуть некую строку, по сути Json. Вот как выглядит отправка ответа клиенту:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

                    String answer = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n" +
                            "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n";

                    printWriter.print(answer);
                    printWriter.print(some_json);

                    printWriter.close();
```

Json-овская строка довольно длинная (около 13Кб). Проблема в том, что сервак возвращает ее не полностью, а обрывает на каком-то месте. При этом, если просто обновлять страничку в браузере, не перезапуская сервак, он может вернуть ее и полностью, обновишь - опять обрезанную. Какое-то непредсказуемое поведение. Возможно проблема кроется в этом printWriter и он что-то мухлюет. Как разобраться не знаю. Спасибо.

Comment: а разве `flush()` перед `close()` не надо делать?

Comment: При создании объекта printWriter указывается true  - флаг, означающий autoflush.